# Group and Aggregate strings based on order and key fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in a PostegreSQL table that looks like this:

```
text                     field1   field2    ID
Lorem ipsum dolor             A        B     1
Donec tristique ips           A        C     2
Donec ut imperdiet neque,     A        B     3
Suspendisse urna nunc,        A        B     4
tristique auctor libero.      A        C     5
sem varius nec                A        C     6
```

I want to add some sort of second ID that groups the text by field1 and field2 while keeping the order of the table. Something like this:

```
text                     field1   field2    ID    ID2
Lorem ipsum dolor             A        B     1      1
Donec tristique ips           B        C     2      2
Donec ut imperdiet neque,     A        B     3      3
Suspendisse urna nunc,        A        B     4      3
tristique                     B        C     5      4
sem varius nec                B        C     6      4
sem neque auctor              B        C     7      4
```

I would then group and aggregate my text field based on that ID2 field.
The end result would look like this:

```
text                                                 field1    field2   ID2
Lorem ipsum dolor                                     A         B         1
Donec tristique ips                                   B         C         2 
Donec ut imperdiet neque, Suspendisse urna nunc,      A         B         3     
tristique sem varius necsem neque auctor              B         C         4
```

What query would I need to run in order to get this result?

Thank you,

Comment: `string_agg(  ... order by ...)`

Comment: What do you mean by "order of the table"? Tables have **no** inherent order. Without an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT`, the server is free to return results in any order that is convenient. If you don't have some column(s) to specify in the `ORDER BY`, you have a problem with your data model.

Comment: By order, I mean concatenate my text field if both field1 and field2 and the same as the previous row like my example above.

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever has said, you can't talk about "previous row" sensibly unless you have some value(s) to order by.

Comment: Let's say I have an ID row to keep track of the order. 1 would and 2 would stay the same, 3 and 4 would be concatenated and same for 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can give an "internal" ordering to any aggregate function:

```
SELECT  array_agg(text ORDER BY id) AS text,
        field1, field2,
        row_number() OVER () AS id2
FROM    t
GROUP BY field1, field2
ORDER BY id2
```

If you are printing the result or pulling it into an application, you may prefer to use `string_agg` instead of `array_agg`, with a `,` for the delimiter.

**EDIT:** Here is a query that identifies "runs" of identical `field1`+`field2` values, when rows are ordered by `id`:

```
SELECT  array_agg(text ORDER BY id),
        field1, field2,
        row_number() OVER ()
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*,
                (SELECT MIN(t2.id)
                 FROM   t t2
                 WHERE  t2.id <= t.id
                 AND    t2.field1 = t.field1
                 AND    t2.field2 = t.field2
                 AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1
                                    FROM    t t3
                                    WHERE   t3.id < t.id
                                    AND     t3.id > t2.id
                                    AND     (t3.field1 <> t.field1
                                    OR       t3.field2 <> t.field2))) AS g
        FROM    t
        ) AS x
GROUP BY g, field1, field2
ORDER BY g
;
```

I consider this query somewhat ridiculous, and I don't vouch for its performance, but it does what you're asking for. Also since you seem unwilling to accept numerous people explaining that a table has no natural ordering, you should really find a good book about the relational model and read it.

Comment: How do you get ID2?

Comment: Ha ha, you're the one that mentioned it! So you want to generate it?

Comment: Yeah it was my missing step :P 
Ok I tried your script and it works but it's not exactly what I'm looking to do.
This concatenates every A B, B C together regardless of their position.
What I'm looking for is: imagine you have dialogs and one dialog is spread over multiple rows, I want to have one row per dialog.

Comment: As others have said, in SQL rows have no "position", because a table is an unordered *set*. You can impose an order with `ORDER BY`, but there is no inherent ordering. Anyway, if you want one row per dialog, how do you identify which rows are from the same dialog? That's what you should group by.

Comment: My rows are in order to begin with in my data so the original order is the right order. If I have 2 rows with A B, 1 row A C and another row AB, it should give me A B (2 rows concatenated into one), A C (one row) and A B (one row).